# Add Content to Individual Cells of Dynamically Created Table

Tags: javascript, html-table, handlebars.js

I'm working on a Duda website widget (similar to a wordpress plugin) which will allow the user of the website editor to dynamically create a table. So far, I have the ability to create the table down, but I am stuck on allowing the user to add content to the individual cells.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function tableCreate(){
//get this element ID
var a = $(element).attr('id');
// pass Id to getElement
var e = document.getElementById(a);
//create table element
var b = document.createElement('table');
//user input for table width
var c = data.config.tW1;
//user input for number of rows
var d = parseInt(data.config.rowSelection1);
//user input for number of 
var f = parseInt(data.config.columnSelection1);

//create table dependent on user input
b.style.width  = (c + '%');
//b.style.height = 
b.style.border = '3px solid green';
//i = rows j = columns
for(var i = 0; i < d; i++){
    var tr = b.insertRow();
    for(var j = 0; j < f; j++){
        if(i == d && j == f){
            break;
        } else {
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Table Cell'));
            td.style.border = '1px solid black';

        }
    }
}
e.appendChild(b);
}
tableCreate();
```

I can retrieve user input. For example lets say I added a text input, I assign a variable to the input for the user (textInput1), I retrieve that by using data.config.textInput1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. First the editor allows for user input of unordered lists. The trick is to take their list and convert it into a table. You can have them designate which columns they want by splitting words with any symbol you want. I used a ,

heres a jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zqmku0n4/1/

```
<ul id='my_oddly_formatted_list1' class='userList'>
    <li > Column A,Column B,Column C, Column D</li>
    <li>Value A1,Value B1,Value C1,</li>
    <li>Value A2,Value B1,Value C2,</li>
    <li>Value A3,Value B1,Value C3,</li>
    <li>Value A4,Value B1,Value C4, Value D2</li>
    <li>Value A4,Value B1,Value C4,</li>
    <li>Value A4,Value B1,Anything,</li>
    <li>Value A4,Value B1,Value C4,</li>
    <li>Value A4,Value B1,Value C4,</li>
</ul>




jQuery.fn.tableCreate = function(){
    return this.each(function() {
    //get this element ID (don't need for example)
    //var a = $(element).attr('id');
    // pass Id to getElement
    //var e = document.getElementById(a);

    //create table element
    var b = $('<table>');
    //b.css('background-color', 'orange')
    //b.style.border = '3px solid green'; // this can be an input */
    //user input for table width
    var c = '100%';
    b.css('width', c)
    console.log(c);
    //user input for number of rows
    //var d = parseInt(data.config.rowSelection1);
    var d = $('<tbody>');
    //user input for number of 
    //var f = parseInt(data.config.columnSelection1);  


    //create table dependent on user li input
        $(this).find('li').each(function(i){
        var f = $(this).html().split(',');
      if (i == 0) { 
            var g = $('<thead>')
          var h = 'orange'
         /*  g.style.backgroundColor = (h); */
          var j = $('<tr>')
          $.each(f, function(k) {
                j.append($('<th>').html(f[k]));
          });
          b.append(g.append(j));
              d.append(j);
         } else {
         var j = $('<tr>');
         $.each(f, function(k){
            j.append($('<td style="border:1px solid black; padding:10px;  ">').html(f[k]));
         });
         d.append(j);
         }
      });
      $(this).after(b.append(d)).remove();
    });
 };

$('ul.userList').tableCreate();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to let the user edit the table (assuming HTML 5 browser): You can just add contentEditable=contentEditable to your table

```
<table contenteditable="contenteditable">
<tr>
<td>a</td><td>b</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>c</td><td>d</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I've edited my post to specify. This isn't a "user" of the website, but rather a user in the duda website builder. This works similar to a custom plugin in wordpress.

Comment: So why can't your plugin use contenteditable? When you say "stuck on letting users add content..." what is it about this solution that isn't working?

Comment: Mainly because this allows all users whom visit the website to edit the cell contents, and Upon refresh any change will be reverted back to its orginal cell contents, in my code this would be "Table Cell" 

It was poor choice of words on my part, but the user in this case would be the one using the website editor, I.E placing the plugin on the website. Not the user viewing the website.